# Shouldn't we hide progress bars for badges that have already been awarded?

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, badge-progress

This is in the context of the little hover card that pops up over your review queue progress, i.e.:

[image]

What's the value in continuing to show me the progress bar for Civic Duty here? I've already been awarded it and would rather just see the two remaining progress bars (Copy Editor and Electorate).

Shouldn't we hide the progress bar for badges that have already been awarded?

Comment: I don't see the harm in it. You can easily see this way which badges you've already earned. Is there a reason we should hide it? It only takes up screen space when clicked, and then still not that much. Also, what if a user has all badges for that queue? Display nothing?

Comment: That would be fine by me, personally.

Comment: I would call the [KISS principe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) here. Let's have it simple since there is no harm done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's difficult to visually distinguish a progress bar that's full from one at 99.9% -- Yes, once the bar is full it should be replaced by a checkmark.